# How does ssh read the password that I type in?

Tags: ssh, pty

My understanding is that if I type the following command in my xterm:

`$ ssh ir@localhost
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ir@localhost's password:`

Then the stdin and stdout of the `ssh` process are both connected to the pty. So when I type in the password, `ssh` just reads it from stdin.

But my mental model fails to explain this:

`$ yes | ssh ir@localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ir@localhost's password: 
...
...
zsh: command not found: y
...`

Here, `yes`'s stdin is connected to the pty, and `yes`'s stdout is piped to `ssh`'s stdin. So `ssh` should be getting a deluge of `y`s, but it is smart enough to tell that its stdin is not a tty, and that the contents of stdin should not be interpreted as the password. Instead, the `y`s are buffered, and once the login succeeds, they are delivered directly to the bash process on the remote end.

**But then how is ssh able to get the password that I am typing in?** The pty sends my password to `yes`, which drops it on the floor.

Also, `ssh`'s claim to not allocate a pty appears to be a lie. The following snippet prints out whether or not stdin is tty:

`$ [ -t 0 ] && echo true || echo false;
true`

When I pipe this command to ssh, it initially prints out "false", as expected:

`$ echo "[ -t 0 ] && echo true || echo false;" | ssh ir@localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ir@localhost's password: 
...
false
$ [ -t 0 ] && echo true || echo false;
true`

But when I run the same command on the remote shell, it prints out "true". I can even open up `vim`, and when I resize my local terminal, the `vim` resizes the text that it is displaying appropriately. This can only be possible if the `ssh` client sends information about the resizing over the wire, and if `sshd` notifies the `vim` process, just like a pty would.

Interestingly, when I hit Ctrl+C, the `ssh` session is immediately terminated. My explanation for this is that the pty intercepts the Ctrl+C and sends a SIGINT to both `yes` and `ssh`. If `ssh` had allocated a pty, it would intercept the signal and transmit it over the wire to the remote host, and whatever process running remotely would be the one interrupted. But since `ssh` did *not* allocate a pty, it simply died. So this part is expected...but I still don't understand why `[ -t 0 ]` passes on the remote shell, and how `ssh` is able to read the password even when `yes` is piped to it.

Comment: `ssh` doesn't read the password from `stdin`. Probably from `/dev/tty` which is directly from the active terminal.

Comment: @lurker Ah, that makes sense. I had no idea that that existed.